# Issue while setting up a DSN while creating a linked server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, amazon-ec2, linked-server, dsn

I am trying to set up a linked server to my sql from sql server. However I am encountering problems while setting up the dsn. Reffering this [link](http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/) for help.

[image]

My MySQL database resides on Amazon ec2 ubuntu server and my sql server resides on Windows server 2012.